# How to read response as Observable[String] with sttp

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, monix, sttp

I'm using sttp client. I want to intepret response as strings divided by lines, eg `Observable[String]`

Here sttp streaming api:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

import com.softwaremill.sttp._
import com.softwaremill.sttp.okhttp.monix.OkHttpMonixBackend
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.reactive.Observable

implicit val sttpBackend = OkHttpMonixBackend()

val res: Task[Response[Observable[ByteBuffer]]] = sttp
  .post(uri"someUri")
  .response(asStream[Observable[ByteBuffer]])
  .send()
```

So how I can get `Observable[String]`?

Here some ideas:

**1.** Is there a simple way to `split` Observable by lines?
**2.** Or maybe I can get raw `InputStream` from response, so I can easly split it, but I can't find way to use something like `asStream[InputStream]`
**3.** Or maybe just use http backend witout `sttp` layer?

Comment: hey @zella! Have you been able to solve the problem?

Comment: @ErnestSadykov No, I didn't worked with sttp last time. But for example you can see here https://github.com/zella/rx-process2/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/zella/rxprocess2/RxNuProcessBuilderSpec.scala#L95 How to decode `Observable[Array[Bytes]]` to strings. rxjava `Flowable` easy converts to monix.

Comment: Note, that `Strings` from link above has methods to split `Observable[String]` byLine. Example: https://github.com/zella/tuapse-play/blob/master/src/main/java/org/zella/tuapse/play/torrent/impl/DefaultWebTorrent.java#L41

Answer (score 2):

Your base problem is how to convert an `Observable[ByteBuffer]` into an `Observable[String]`, where each `String` is a line, correct?

You can use the method `bufferWithSelector(selector: Observable[S]): Observable[Seq[A]]`.
This method will buffer the Observable until the selector Observable emits an element.

I made a small example using `Int`s:

```scala
import monix.reactive.Observable
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val source = Observable.range(0, 1000, 1)
  .delayOnNext(100.milliseconds)

val selector = source.filter(_ % 10 == 0)

val buffered = source.bufferWithSelector(selector)
  .map(_.foldLeft("")((s, i) => s + i.toString)) // This folds the Seq[Int] into a String for display purposes

buffered.foreach(println)
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/nrc0wai/1)

---

Of course, this has a major drawback: The underlying Observable `source` will be evaluated twice. You can see this by modifying the above example:

```scala
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here

import monix.reactive.Observable
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val source = Observable.range(0, 1000, 1)
  .delayOnNext(100.milliseconds)
  .map {x => println(x); x}  // <------------------

val selector = source.filter(_ % 10 == 0)

val buffered = source.bufferWithSelector(selector)
  .map(_.foldLeft("")((s, i) => s + i.toString))

buffered.foreach(println)
```

This will print every number twice.

---

To fix this, you have to convert the `source` Observable into a hot Observable:

```
import monix.reactive.Observable
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val source = Observable.range(0, 1000, 1)
  .delayOnNext(100.milliseconds)
  .map {x => println(x); x}
  .publish // <-----------------------------

// source is now a ConnectableObservable and will start emitting elements
// once you call source.connect()

val selector = source.filter(_ % 10 == 0)

val buffered = source.bufferWithSelector(selector)
  .map(_.foldLeft("")((s, i) => s + i.toString))

buffered.foreach(println)

source.connect() // <---------------------------
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/94tbXs5/1)

The only thing you need to do is to modify the selector to emit items only
when a line feed is encountered.

I would suggest splitting the `Observable[ByteBuffer]` into an `Observable[Byte]` first (using `flatMap`) to avoid headaches.